# R8 obfuscation results in @PropertyName not working causing DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, obfuscation, android-r8

Only when I obfuscate my app do I get the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: data`
```

This applies to class properties which begin with a lowercase letter but are stored in firebase beginning with a capital letter - e.g. `val data` where they are annotated with `@PropertyName("Data")`

There are two firebase dependency modules (firebase-database and firebase-firestore) which both contain `@PropertyName` and when I change my class imports from:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName
```

to

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.PropertyName
```

then the crash disappears but the data isn't fetched.

I'm not allowed to share the db details but the model has this structure:

```
import com...ResponseBase
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties
import com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class TxResponse constructor(
    @PropertyName("Data")
    val data: Data = Data(),
    @PropertyName("AnId")
    val anId: String = "",
    @PropertyName("AResult")
    val aResult: String = "",
    @PropertyName("moreData")
    val moreData: MoreData = MoreData()
) : ResponseBase()

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Data constructor(
    @PropertyName("SomeId")
    val someId: String = "",
    @PropertyName("Label")
    val label: String = "",
    ...
)

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class MoreData(
    @PropertyName("Code")
    val code: Long = 0
)
```

Just for background,
I am `keep`ing the models and firebase classes. I'm using firebase-firestore version 22.0.0 and firebase-database-ktx version 19.5.1. Using the most recent versions doesn't fix the problem. Unfortunately I can't change the database.

Any help would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also add the content of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an explanation and I don't understand this, but it may help someone else...

This is the line which was causing the exception:

```
-keep class com...response.** { *; }
```

If I remove this, the exception goes away, but I still need to keep the fields and the solution is to use this rule instead

```
-keepnames class com...response.** { <fields>; }
```

However, the first rule is closer to the one recommended in the official docs and is a broader keep rule:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard
https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/refcard